# how to properly use $1 in an alias with two arguments

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

i have to compare a number of files and I don't want to change the command in two places all the time. so i want to create an alias in bash.

```
alias gd='gvimdiff $1 dir/$1'
```

so that i can get

```
gvimdiff res.tex dir/res.tex
```

just by typing

```
gd res.tex
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot use aliases this way, however, you can define a function do to the same thing.

```
function gd() {
    gvimdiff $1 dir/$1
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do it as a single command in a CLI?

Comment: That is a single command.

Comment: so i did "function gd() { gvimdiff $1 dir/$1; }"  but when i run it: "gd res.tex", as an output i get contents of "dir" . did i miss something?

Comment: 'function gd () { gvimdiff $1 dir/$1; }' worked thank you

Comment: yep, no problem! Glad to help!

Comment: Idk when it has changed (saw the question is 5 year old) but in fact, if you do `alias myecho='echo $1'` will work. The big problem starts if you wanna use `echo \`pgrep $1\`` or somewhat like that.

Answer (score 5):

Aliases don't work that way. <s>You should be able to use history substitution (e.g. `!!:1`),</s> ([no, `bash` doesn't allow that](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions)) or define a [function](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) instead.

Comment: can you suggest a link so i can find out more about this? googling didn't give me much

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple tried it in kde neon, ubuntu, manjaro, arch all bash

```
alias gd="gvimdiff '$1' dir/'$1'"
```

just add the following commas it will work.

Comment: there is no commas?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to previous answers, this seems to just work as of at least bash 5.0.18.

```bsh
alias gd="gvimdiff $1 dir/$1"
```

(Make sure not to use single-quotes, as they'll escape the `$`).

This probably only works with the shell option 'expand_aliases' enabled.
To enable this type

```bsh
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

in the terminal. Or better yet write the line into '.bashrc' to make it permanent, if it's not already there.